# resedit issues errors with standard Microsoft header files

Tags: c++, c, windows

When I started using resedit v1.6.6, it displayed errors like "right parenthesis expected" when I added standard include paths for files like "windows.h".

It looks like resedit fails to parse valid header files.

Comment: Microsoft's support for C is known to be less than optimal, so to say. Especially their headers can be full of noncompliant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to add a directory with empty files for each header file resedit complains about. By adding dummy files on a path *before* standard header file paths, resedit will prefer the dummy files.

I needed to replace

- corecrt.h
- vadefs.h
- vcruntime.h